# Congruence properties of $\sum{\binom{n}{k}}^2t^k$ $\mod{(t+1)}.$

Tags: polynomials, congruences

In arXiv:math/0407326 Emeric Deutsch and Bruce Sagan proved that  the Delannoy numbers 
$$D_n=\sum{\binom{n}{k}}^22^k $$

satisfy $D_n\not\equiv0\mod3$ if and only if $n=2m$ with $\binom{2m}{m}\not\equiv 0\mod{(3)}.$

It seems that this can be generalized to:
$$\sum{\binom{n}{k}}^2t^k\not\equiv0\mod{(t+1)}$$  if and only if 
$$n=2m$$ with $$\binom{2m}{m}\not\equiv 0\mod{(t+1)}.$$

My question is: Is this result known and if so where is it published?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my question was a generalization of a rather trivial reformulation of the cited result.
The congruence follows from the identity
$\sum{\binom{n}{k}}^2t^k =\sum\binom{2j}{j}\binom{n}{2j}t^j(1+t)^{n-2j}.$